# How to make a scala library?

Tags: scala, static-libraries

I'm not a very experienced programmer and very new to scala. I am in a situation where I have to write a library for other people to use. I do not have access to the repo of the people I am doing this for, so I cannot simply write a class for them - it needs to be library-type thing that they can include when building their own code. How does one go about achieving this? Should I build a .jar from my source, and then they'll be able to include it somehow, or is there no other way than to directly provide the source code to them?

Comment: it's the same way you build a Java project.

Comment: Are you using `sbt`?

Comment: Yes, I am using sbt. And I'm not that familiar with publishing Java projects either. This is pretty much the first time I'm doing something like this :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The publish approach of Aleksey's answer implies that they can link to your library through Maven or Ivy (for example, they are using also a build tool like sbt or Maven). The advantage of this is that their build system can handle transitive dependencies automatically. This is probably the best approach.

Of course there is also always the old fashioned way of building a jar that they include as a manual dependency. `sbt package` will give you a plain jar of your library, not including your own dependencies or the scala library (if those are needed, they will have to add their respective jars as well).

Finally, using something like [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), you can build a fat jar that includes the dependencies of your library as well. The disadvantage could be that you must make sure they do not depend on the same type of libraries, because they are not managed automatically this way.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using SBT you can use `publish` command. Refer to the docs [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html).

There are 2 options:

1. `publish` to publish to remote repository
2. `publishLocal` to publish to your file system.

If you need a more sophisticated release procedure take a look at `sbt-release` [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release).

You can find lots of examples on internet but be careful to check how old they are. SBT has improved these features a lot, so it's much easier to publish these days.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.